# ViewController (Declared in Binary Framework) not detected by XIB / Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

XIB Or Storyboard failed to find my UIViewController defined in a framework file. Please check below details.

1. Created a view Controller called "MainTempVC" by extending ParentView controller "ParentViewUV". Parent ViewController "ParentViewUV" is defined / declared in a binary framework "SysBaseLib".

```
import UIKit
import SysBaseLib
class MainTempVC: ParentViewUV, ParentViewUVDelegate {

    
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.parentViewUVDelegate = self
    }
    
    func viewType(type: Int) {
        
        if(type == 0){
        }
        
    }

    @IBAction func unwindTomainTempVC(_ segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
        
    }
}
```

2. Now, in I am trying to assign "MainTempVC" UIViewController to ViewController in Storyboard but storyboard does not suggest a name of "MainTempVC".
   It works only when i add class name manually via Copy/Paste.

[image: Storyboard-set class]

When i remove "ParentViewUV" from UIViewController extension, it is working properly.

[image: Working on remove ParentUV]

```
import UIKit

class temp2VC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

    @IBAction func unwindTotemp2VC(_ segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
        
    }

}
```

My BuildPhases (Libraries)

[image: Libraries]

"ParentViewUV" is defined / declared in a binary framework.

Actually i am trying to use unwind segue method from storyboard. But when i am trying to add it, storyboard is not giving an option to use unwindsegue defined in "MainTemVC" file.

I have tried to add my framework into linked binaries section of "Build Settings" and also i have added my library to "Library search Path" but nothing is working.

**How do i access ViewController in storyboard which is defined in binary framework?**

Comment: Does changing "Module" and "Inherits from Target Module" help?

Comment: No, it doen't help. 

Also, "MainTemVC" is a part of current readable source code (Inherited Module - target module).